# AWS IoT Device Management from external web app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, iot, aws-iot

I'm looking for a way to interact/manage my iot devices from a web app.

I know AWS FleetHub is a new service that enables device monitoring + alerts, but only available in North Virginia.

Are there apis i can directly interact with for managing IoT devices or is there a way i can manage them with a Lambda function(With the right permissions) as shown below?

Or is the only way to manage IoT devices in the aws console.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fleet Hub is generally available in

- US East (N. Virginia)
- US East (Ohio)
- US West (Oregon)
- Asia Pacific (Seoul)
- Asia Pacific (Singapore)
- Asia Pacific (Sydney)
- Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
- Canada (Central)
- Europe (Frankfurt)
- Europe (Ireland)
- Europe (London)

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/05/fleet-hub-monitor-interact-iot-device-fleets-now-generally-available/

**AWS SDK**.
If your region is not available you can use AWS SDK to build your own (following just Node.js SDK)

- [Iot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Iot.html) to list Things
- [IotData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IotData.html) to get Thing shadow

And give Lambda IAM role permission to access the above features

**AWS CLI**.
you can also using aws cli to manage device from your terminal

- [iot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot/index.html)
- [iot-data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot-data/index.html)